# Validate cart before placing order

Tags: magento2, orders, validation

I'm trying to find the best practice in order to do a cart validation before an order is placed. if the cart meets my requirements the order should proceed. If not it should show a custom error message and prevent the order from being created.

Any good tips on how to achieve this?

I created a preference for Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement and do the validation on the savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder method but I'm not feeling confortable with this solution and was hoping to do this via a plugin or an observer :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: do you want this to be actioned on the cart page or the checkout

Comment: I wish this to be activated on the final step of checkout, meaning this should trigger when the customer presses the "Place order" button. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is how to do it.

**/vendor/module/etc/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">   
     <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
        <observer name="checkcout_page" instance="vendor\mdodule\Observer\CheckShoppingCartObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**/vendor/module/Observer/CheckShoppingCartObserver.php**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;

class CheckShoppingCartObserver implements ObserverInterface
{  
    protected $redirect;
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $productRepository;  
    protected $categoryRepository;  
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
    protected $cart;
    public function __construct(
        RedirectInterface                                 $_redirect,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session                   $_checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository          $_productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface  $_categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $_customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart

    )
    {
        $this->redirect                    = $_redirect;
        $this->checkoutSession             = $_checkoutSession;
        $this->productRepository           = $_productRepository;
        $this->categoryRepository          = $_categoryRepository;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $_customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
         $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
         //In my case I redirect the customer to the cart page if the condition is not met       

         If( condition not met)
         {
           $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
           $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'checkout/cart');
         }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this does not fire on clicking "place order" rather it fires when the checkout page is loaded which is not what the original question was asking